# Syntax error on "=" NodeJs in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

I have developed a NodeJs(v10.19.0) server on windows.
I now need to transfer it to a linux server running Ubuntu 20.04
When I try to start the server, I have a syntax error on a "=".

Here's the complet error:

```
/puppeteer/scraping-bot.js:6
    static websiteRegex = /^(https?\:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})(\/[\w\W]*)*$/gm
                        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/routes/scraping.js:1:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here's the code that outputs the error:

```
class ScrapingBot {
    
    static websiteRegex = /^(https?\:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})(\/[\w\W]*)*$/gm
    static phoneRegex = /\+?\d{1,4}?[-.\s]?\(?\d{1,3}?\)?[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,9}/g;
    static addressRegex = /(([a-zA-Z-éÉèÈàÀùÙâÂêÊîÎôÔûÛïÏëËüÜçÇæœ'.]*\s)\d*(\s[a-zA-Z-éÉèÈàÀùÙâÂêÊîÎôÔûÛïÏëËüÜçÇæœ']*)*,)*\d*(\s[a-zA-Z-éÉèÈàÀùÙâÂêÊîÎôÔûÛïÏëËüÜçÇæœ']*)+,\s([\d]{5})\s[a-zA-Z-éÉèÈàÀùÙâÂêÊîÎôÔûÛïÏëËüÜçÇæœ']+/
    ...
    }
```

I set up Git with nano if that helps...

I have already tried to replace the "=".

Comment: [Static class fields](https://node.green/#ES2022-features-static-class-fields) aren't supported in Node 10. Also Node 10 isn't supported at all any more: https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in here, static class fields are not supported as of Node 10 ->
https://node.green/#ES2022-features-static-class-fields

**edit**: @jonrsharpe also answered this

Comment: Ok ! thanks I will Update it